# How to use the xslt-xquery-serialization namespace to export to JSON

Tags: xquery, saxon, xquery-3.0

I'm trying to use the "Convert XML to JSON" example from WikiBooks here https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XQuery/Convert_XML_to_JSON

```
xquery version "3.0";

declare namespace output="http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";

declare option output:method "json";
declare option output:media-type "application/json";

let $test := <root>
  <!-- simple elements -->
  <aaa>AAA</aaa>
  <bbb>BBB</bbb>
  <ccc>CCC</ccc>
  <!-- complex (nested) element -->
  <ddd>
     <eee>
        <fff>
           <ggg>GGG</ggg>
        </fff>
     </eee>
  </ddd>
  <!-- duplicate elements -->
  <hhh>HHH1</hhh>
  <hhh>HHH2</hhh>
  <hhh>HHH3</hhh>
  <hhh>HHH4</hhh>
  <!-- attributes -->
  <iii a1="123" a2="456" a3="789"/>
  <!-- attributes with text content-->
  <jjj a1="123" a2="456" a3="789">JJJ</jjj>
</root>

return $test
```

I'm using the Saxon parser, with this command line

```
java -cp Saxon-HE-9.8.0-8.jar net.sf.saxon.Query xml2json.xqy
```

But it's still returning the $test variable as xml, what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wikibook article you reference is incorrect. According to the relevant specification, XSLT and XQuery Serialization 3.1, the JSON serialization method treats XML nodes [as follows](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization-31/#json-output):

> A node in the data model instance is serialized to a JSON string by outputting the result of serializing the node using the method specified by the `json-node-output-method` parameter. The node is serialized with the serialization parameter `omit-xml-declaration` set to `yes` and with no other serialization parameters set.

In other words, an XQuery processor like Saxon is supposed to serialize XML nodes as JSON strings.

To achieve the goal promised by the wikibook article, you would need to transform the document into maps and arrays or into an intermediary format that you can feed to the [`xml-to-json()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-xml-to-json)` function.